# Command Button action not working

Tags: jsf, redirect

I have this dataTable:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{orderController.orderList}" var="order"
                                     styleClass="table table-striped">
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">#</f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{order.orderNo}" escape="false"/>
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">Cliente</f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{order.client}" escape="false"/>
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">Data</f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{order.date}" escape="false"/>
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header">Status</f:facet>
                                <h:outputText value="#{order.status}" escape="false"/>
                            </h:column>
                            <h:column>
                                <f:facet name="header"></f:facet>
                                <h:form>
                                    <h:commandButton action="#{orderController.orderDetail}" value="Detalhe" styleClass="btn btn-info"/>
                                </h:form>
                            </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

I'm showing a list of orders and each list has a button "Detail" that will redirect the user to the `orderDetail.html` page inside `views/fornecedores`.

I've debugged and when I click on the `commandButton`, it is not calling my bean function.[

I have also tried this: `<h:commandButton action="views/fornecedores/orderDetail.html" value="Detalhe" styleClass="btn btn-info"/>` and nothing, it keeps redirecting me to the same page, `orderSearch.html`.

What I need is to call the method that will receive a `orderNo` parameter and will load the object and redirect to the `orderDetail.html` page.

What am I doing wrong or what is the best way to this approach?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this particular case, that can happen when you're nesting forms which is illegal in HTML. This can also happen when the `#{orderController}` is request scoped and the `orderList` content depends on a request based value which causes that the list is incompatibly changed when the form submit is to be processed.

So, make sure that you aren't nesting multiple `<h:form>` components in each other and make sure that the `#{orderController}` is a `@ViewScoped` bean and that you aren't manipulating the `orderList` in its getter method.

#### See also:

- [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked)

---

As to your concrete functional requirement, the `<h:link>` with `<f:param>` and `<f:viewParam>` is a more sane approach for this. It's bookmarkable and more SEO friendly. See also [Communication in JSF 2.0 - Processing GET request parameters](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ProcessingGETRequestParameters).

Comment: You are correct, I have several `<h:form>` tags and I know it is terribly wrong. I'm gonna try using the tags you mentioned.